# Is there a way to open a dialogbox when email send in apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, google-workspace

I am creating a G-Mail Add-In with apps script.

What I wanna do is when user send an e-mail a dialogbox will open and user will click to yes from dialogbox then mail will be sent.

Is there any event or any way to do it?

I did this with ItemSend and OnMessageSend event in Office JS in Outlook but I didn't find this kind of event in apps script. It doesn't have to be apps script If is there any other way I would use it

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
function sendEmail() {
  let r = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Send Email?","Just click the appropriate button",SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if(r.getSelectedButton() == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.YES) {
    Logger.log("Send email");//Put emaiil sending code here
  } else {
    Logger.log("Don't Send")
  }
}
```

- [Ui Prompt Response](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response)

Comment: that could work but what i want is that ui had to open when user compose a mail and click the send button

Comment: gas does not intteract directly with the gmail ui

Comment: is there a way to cancel a mail if it has some word that i dont want to send? For example if mail has a word "orange" than mail got cancel. Is it possible with app script?

Comment: Not if you have already sent it.

Comment: I want to cancel the mail before sent it.For example If there is a prohibited word in the e-mail, a pop-up will appear and it will say that the e-mail cannot be sent.

Comment: You can do that by search for the word and it is found then not sending the email but I would need to have the send email code inorder to go any further.  Where does the recipent,subject and message come from?

Comment: I take message with this code, var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId). But i want to execute this code when user send a mail

Comment: Please don't tell me what you do.  Show me the code. Were all supposed to be programmers here. - [Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, or anyone who writes code because they love it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please provide a [mcve] so that we can see the code that you are using to create the problem.  Please post it into you question.

Comment: there is no code actually.Even if i can write hello world after user send a mail that would work for me for now. All I am asking for is there a way to caught when user send a mail in app script?

Comment: You can alway use the ui.prompt to open a dialog